# TypeScript does not recognize URLSearchParams as iterable

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am getting the following error trying to build a small TypeScript project with yarn & webpack:

```
TS2549: Type 'URLSearchParams' is not an array type or a string type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

I'm trying to use a Node built-in `URLSearchParams` object in a simple loop:

```js
for (let [name, value] of searchParams) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The Node LTS version 12 docs show that [the Symbol.iterator method exists](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/url.html#url_urlsearchparams_symbol_iterator). It works in the Node REPL.

I found a [closed issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15243) in the TypeScript repo from 2017 that supposedly resolved this error. But I also tried using `searchParams.entries()` and the validator did not recognize it as an available property. So it feels like my TypeScript has a very out-of-date definition for URLSearchParams. Maybe this is just a packaging issue but I don't know how to investigate further. The `yarn.lock` file shows appropriate node types:

```
"@types/node@^12":
  version "12.12.53"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/node/-/node-12.12.53.tgz#be0d375933c3d15ef2380dafb3b0350ea7021129"
  integrity sha512-51MYTDTyCziHb70wtGNFRwB4l+5JNvdqzFSkbDvpbftEgVUBEE+T5f7pROhWMp/fxp07oNIEQZd5bbfAH22ohQ==

typescript@^3.9.7:
  version "3.9.7"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/typescript/-/typescript-3.9.7.tgz#98d600a5ebdc38f40cb277522f12dc800e9e25fa"
  integrity sha512-BLbiRkiBzAwsjut4x/dsibSTB6yWpwT5qWmC2OfuCg3GgVQCSgMs4vEctYPhsaGtd0AeuuHMkjZ2h2WG8MSzRw==
```

When I look at the local copies of the Typescript definition files I see the addition of Iterable-related properties in `lib.dom.iterable.d.ts` (as mentioned in that closed GitHub issue). Somehow those are being ignored.

I can rewrite my code to use `searchParams.forEach()` instead, but I'd like to understand what's going wrong anyway.

Comment: Is your compiler target "es6" in `tsconfig.json`? That might solve this issue.

Comment: The file has `"target": "es5"`. I did not set up this project, but I don't know why it would be using an old target. It will be running on a Node 12 instance. I tried changing that to `es6`, but Visual Studio Code still gives me the same errors. Haven't actually tried to run the build again.

Comment: I had to reload VS Code.

Comment: `yarn build` still failed with that change too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the original post speculates, the additional definitions in `lib.dom.iterable.d.ts` are not being used. The project's TypeScript config in `tsconfig.json` has to reference that file:

```
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "dom.iterable",
  "es2019"
]
```

With this, TypeScript now understands iterator-related properties for URLSearchParams and about 50 other types referenced in that file. I assume the separation is related to TypeScript backwards compatibility with older ECMAScript flavors, but I don't know.

Comment: For me it's worked only after adding "downlevelIteration": true to tsconfig.json

Comment: For me, adding "DOM.Iterable" worked.

Comment: Adding `@types/node` also helps with adding necessary iterator values.

Comment: I don't have a `lib` key in my `tsconfig`. Can you define this in the `target` key? I have it set to `ES6` currently. I'm getting this error on `searchParams.size` but I'm guessing it's related. `error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'URLSearchParams'.`

Answer (score -1):

1. update typescript
2. delete local node_modules
3. delete package-lock.json | yarn.lock.json
4. install node modules

Answer (score -3):

In my case it was TSLint that complained about having the URLSearchParams object in a template literal.

I used the `toString`-method to return a string instead.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
    }).toString()
const url = `https://www.some_endpoint.com/token?${params}`;
```